# Can I make a single Perl module act as multiple kinds of mod_perl handlers?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl

I'm writing a series of related mod_perl handlers for various login-related functions in Apache, so my Apache config file looks like this (for example)

```
PerlAccessHandler MyApache::MyAccess    
PerlAuthenHandler MyApache::MyAuthen
PerlAuthzHandler MyApache::MyAuthz
```

Each of the modules (`MyAccess`, `MyAuthen`, `MyAuthz`) defines a

```
sub handler() {}
```

Which `mod_perl` calls at the relevant point in the processing of the request.

What I'd like to know is whether there is a way of doing this with one Perl module rather than three (it's just tidier and less work for users to install one module instead of 3)?

Is there some way to define the name of the handler method, perhaps. Or is there a way of detecting from within the `handler()` code which sort of handling I'm supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears from the [mod_perl 2.0 docs](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/coding/coding.html#Method_Handlers) that you can use the "method" syntax to do what you're wanting (I've not tested this):

```
PerlAccessHandler MyApache::MyLoginModule->access_handler
PerlAuthenHandler  MyApache::MyLoginModule->authen_handler
PerlAuthzHandler MyApache::MyLoginModule->authz_handler
```

I believe this will cause mod_perl to call each of the named methods in a static way on your `MyApache::MyLoginModule` class.

You can also create an object to be used when calling a `handler` method if you want to:

```
<Perl>
  use MyApache::MyLoginModule;
  $MyApache::MyLoginModule::access = MyApache::MyLoginModule->new(phase => 'access');
  $MyApache::MyLoginModule::authen = MyApache::MyLoginModule->new(phase => 'authen');
  $MyApache::MyLoginModule::authz = MyApache::MyLoginModule->new(phase => 'authz');
</Perl>

PerlAccessHandler $MyApache::MyLoginModule::access->handler
PerlAuthenHandler $MyApache::MyLoginModule::authen->handler
PerlAuthzHandler $MyApache::MyLoginModule::authz->handler
```

This approach would allow you to have a single `handler` method that could have different behavior based on the properties of the object set up upon object creation.

*Disclaimer: It's been a while since I've worked with this part of mod_perl configuration so your results may vary!*

Comment: Using the "...>access_handler" syntax works. Interestingly the handler gets passed two arguments (the second of which is the request object), unlike the handler() function, which only gets passed the request.

Comment: The two-arg behavior is documented in the link at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one possibility might be using the `push_handlers()` call and setting up the handlers in code rather than in the apache conf file

See here: http://tinyurl.com/bwdeew